# Simultaneous editing textarea from multiple clients in C# .net

Tags: c#, html, .net, textbox, signalr

Suppose I have a .Net web application which users can log into.

Suppose I have a view which is simply a text box and I want all logged in users to be able to write, simultaneously, to a dynamically updating textarea.

I'm going to make a wild guess and say there's probably a library for something like this, and would be easier than trying to do it with native C#/.net.

I already have the signalR library which was needed for other stuff (chat), so if that helps at all, that's awesome. 
Also any actual tutorials on this topic would be greatly appreciated as well.

Thank you.

Comment: You're looking for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_transformation.

Comment: _and what is OT?_ Oh ok. I'll check out that wiki article.

Comment: A contenteditable div element might be an easier way to do this

Comment: @BlueBoy I looked up the contenteditable tag. It seems interesting, and mayhaps it might even be able to do what I want, but wouldnt this create conflicts if two people are trying to edit the text area at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SignalR allows two way client server communication.
It means your client can call sever method, say 
`void UpdateTextArea (DiffInfo diff)`
But also your server can call a method on your clients (one or in room), say `onTextAreaUpdated (diff)`
So you can communicate between the clients.

But SignalR is not about merging. So it's up to you. For example you can use [google-diff-match-patch](https://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/) and collect changes on key up / key down event.

Then you can send this info to the server and breadcast to the rest clients. And apply this event on the rest clients.

And about merge conflicts. You must think about conflicts yourself. And do it definitely on the server side.

Comment: I've been reading on google's diff match patch stuff, and it seems to be pretty close to what i want, at least as a stepping stone. This is probably the way I'll go.